# Initialize base class members from another base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

I tried splitting a data structure into several base classes to reuse the code and data members.
There i encountered the issue that it would greatly simplify my code if i could initialize the members of one base class with the members of another.

```
struct Base1
{
  const int a;
  Base1() : a(3) {}
};

struct Base2
{
  const int b;
  Base2() : b(a*2) {}
};

struct Derived :
  Base1,
  Base2
{  
  Derived() : Base1(), Base2() {}
};
```

Since the above is not possible, I'm searching for a way to achieve something similar, with changing the class Base1 and Base2 as little as possible.
How could I do that?

Comment: Given that the constructor of `Base2` has an invalid initialiser of `b` (accessing a non-existent `a`) the problem isn't one of initialising base classes.  Unless you supply `Base2` with a VALID initialiser list in its constructor, your question is therefore meaningless.

Comment: @Peter The code posted by OP is what he wishes to achieve hypothetically. He explicitely writes `Since the above is not possible,`. Don't disregard every question as meaningless right away. This question is completely fine IMO.

Comment: Why `Base1() : a(3) {}` and not `const int a = 3;` ?

Comment: On a side-note: As you explicitely talked about splitting functionality you should ask yourself whether multiple inheritance is really the way to go. Maybe composition is much better suited here?

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the hint. But the memeber a in the example could be used to initialize multiple bases of type Base2 in my application. Therefore it would be stored multiple times in the final derived class. Thats why i choose inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a clean interface. As `Base2` is not related to `Base1` in any way per your example, the dependency you describe shall be part of it's interface to the outward world. It is not an implementation detail.

As such the correct solution would be to provide an explicit (i don't mean the keyword) constructor:

```
Base2(int a) : b(a*2) {}
```

For `Derived` you then get:

```
Derived() : Base1(), Base2(a) {}
```

Notice that `Base1` gets initialized before `Base2` and as such `a` is already available.